# Clear a Map in nested loop in multithreaded environement

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am working in a multithreaded environment where I have a synchronized multimap. I am using that map in nested loops and I want to clear the value for each transaction in that nested loop. How can I achieve this:

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        final Multimap<Object, Object> map = Multimaps.synchronizedMultimap(ArrayListMultimap.create());

        final List<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();
        listA.add("e");
        listA.add("f");
        listA.add("g");
        final List<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();
        listB.add("e");
        listB.add("f");
        listB.add("g");
        final List<String> listC = new ArrayList<String>();
        listC.add("e");
        listC.add("f");
        listC.add("g");

        for (final String stateId : listA) {
            for (final String gradeList : listB) {
                for (final String subjectList : listC) {
                    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            map.clear();
                            map.put("f", "hi");
                            System.out.println("map before "+map);
                            System.out.println("map after "+map);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(24L, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But this is not resulting in correct output. Sometimes I can see the multiple values and sometimes I see no values while printing the map. Can anyone suggest the changes for this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running all operations at the same time in the executor (well, 10 at a time). These calls here:

```
        map.clear();
        map.put("f", "hi");
        System.out.println("map before "+map);
        System.out.println("map after "+map);
```

are *not* part of a synchronized block, and instructions from multiple threads may be interleaved across them, f.e. the following is a valid interleaving across threads T1 and T2:

```
 T1:       map.clear();
 T2:       map.clear();
 T1:       map.put("f", "hi");
 T2:       map.put("f", "hi");
 T2:       System.out.println("map before "+map);
 T1:       System.out.println("map before "+map);
 T1:       System.out.println("map after "+map);
 T2:       System.out.println("map after "+map);
```

I'll leave how to synchronize across multiple instructions as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Got it !! thanks a lot for the clear explanation. I made use of synchronized block for the map and works like a charm. Thanks a lot for the perfect explanation. :) @TassosBassoukos

Comment: Thats the solution i am looking for. But synchronization is causing serous performance issue here. Its taking forever to complete.It needs to make around 5000 API calls and its taking for ever to complete. Is there any work around for this please?

Comment: Don't use shared state, don't use network calls when holding a lock. Or, use something like rxjava + retrofit.